# PhpStorm: How to switch between tabs and tool window on OSX?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

I have PhpStorm version 2016.1 and [here](https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_mac.pdf) you can see that with <kbd>Control + Tab</kbd> you should to able to "Switch between tabs and tool window", but that don't work for me.

I'm on OSX 10.11.1 and have configured the *Default* keymap in PhpStorm.

Any idea what keys combinations I have to press or why what the doc say is not working?

Comment: *"I'm on OSX 10.11.1 and have configured the **Default keymap**"* Why? On Mac OS you better use Mac specific keymap

Comment: In any case -- what do you see when you hit that shortcut (and keep Ctrl pressed)? On Windows you should see a Switcher -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/navigating-between-files-and-tool-windows.html?search=Nav

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne for your quick reply. With both, the **Default** and the **IntelliJ IDE Classic (OSX)** keymaps I got the same results: the Switcher come up. But what I want is press a key combination and move from the project navigation files to the editor and vice versa, I don't want to select between all the options that are in the Switcher, more when I have many files opened in the editor.

Comment: On Mac you should really use "Mac OS X 10.5 +" keymap. **In any case:** 1) `Ctrl+Tab` works as intended; 2) use `Esc` to get from any tool window back to the editor (well ... excluding Terminal); 3) use `F12` (or whatever you may have there for `Window | Active Tool Window | Jump to Last Tool Window`) to get to the most recently used tool window (even if it's hidden now).

Comment: Hmm, so, if I went to the Database panel and I'm on the editor now, F12 will not lead to the editor. Is really annoying don't have a shortcut for each of the windows|panel|tools that exist in the IDE. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To focus any tool window (the Project view is one of them) you can press Cmd+%Number%, for the Project tool window it's Cmd+1.
To return the focus back to Editor, just press Escape.

Comment: That's only partially correct -- only few (most frequently used) tool windows have such shortcuts. For example -- "Terminal" uses `Alt+F12`; "Database" or "Remote Host" have no shortcuts at all (but you can add them yourself in `Keymap`).

Comment: Correct, that was PHPStorm support replying to a support ticket I posted yesterday. I didn't test the others tools windows but the Project tools shortcut worked fine, that was my main concern. Thanks again for the clarification.